# Minimal implementation of Gtk.Clipboard not functional

Tags: python-3.x, clipboard, introspection, gtk3, pygobject

I am trying to get a minimal implementation of Python3/GTK3's clipboard working. It will work if and only if I run `Gtk.main()`. I have even tried:

```
While Gtk.event_pending():
    Gtk.main_iteration()
```

Without it working.

If I run the script with `Gtk.main()` it behaves as expected allowing me to paste the text into a test GUI editor. This script puts a text string `t` into the clipboard. The string text will be there if and only if `Gtk.main()` is called. If it is not called, but clipboard buffer with be cleared of whatever was there, but empty. I would really appreciate help on this. Any ideas how to make it work without calling `Gtk.main()`?

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository import Gdk
import signal

class Chars(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.connect('destroy', Gtk.main_quit)
        self.show_all()
        self.cb = Gtk.Clipboard.get(Gdk.SELECTION_CLIPBOARD)
        t='Some text'
        self.cb.set_text(t, -1)
        while Gtk.events_pending():
            Gtk.main_iteration()




def main():
    chars = Chars()
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
    # Gtk.main() # works if this is uncommented

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Regards,
Narnie

Answer (score 1):

You have to call [`gtk_clipboard_store`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-Clipboards.html#gtk-clipboard-store) to store the clipboard content for other programs to use.

The way the clipboard works is that, when program B wants the clipboard content, it has to get it from the program A which had set the clipboard data. Program A must have some callbacks to give that clipboard data to program B.

That means when a program A ends, program B won't be able to call program A's callbacks. For that reason Gtk has the `gtk_clipboard_store` function. What that function does give the clipboard "ownership" to program C, so after program A ends the clipboard data set by program A is still available for program B in program C.

If you use the `clipboard_set_data` family of functions, the Gtk library takes care of that when the main Gtk loop ends. Since you don't want to start the Gtk main loop you will have to call `gtk_clipboard_store` yourself.

**TL;DR** simplest clipboard snippet:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

clipboard = Gtk.Clipboard.get(Gdk.SELECTION_CLIPBOARD)
clipboard.set_text("Does a text of all texts contain itself?", -1)
clipboard.store()
```